# family relation in prolog :descendantTree

Tags: prolog

I want recursively store a family relation in a list structure. I have the following code:

```
descendantTree(X,[X]) :-
    \+ parent(X,_).

descendantTree(X,L) :-
    forall(parent(X,Y), descendantTree(Y,YL)),
    append([X],[YL],L).

parent(john, paul).
parent(john, mary).
parent(paul, henry).
parent(paul, june).
parent(mary, adam).
parent(henry, helen).
```

What I expected is like:

```
L =[john,[paul,[henry,[helen]],[june]],[mary,[adam]]]
```

But actually it just return:

```
L = [john, _9250].
```

Could you tell me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `forall/2` predicate implements a generate and test loop using negation. It can be defined as:

```
% for all solutions of Generate, Test is true
forall(Generate, Test) :-
    \+ (Generate, \+ Test)).
```

The use of negation means that no bindings will be returned when a call succeeds. In your case, that means that you're calling:

```
append([X],[_],L)
```

hence the result you get:

```
L = [john, _9250].
```

Look instead into the *all-solutions* family of predicates: `bagof/3`, `setof/3`, and `findall/3` and then consider editing your question with your findings.